# How to unhide one of multiple hidden sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I want by clicking a button to unhide one sheet only and then click again to unhide another.

```vb
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = False Then
    invi = invi + 1
    End If
Next

Do Until invi = 1:
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Visible = True
    invi = invi + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You do not need the counter or the Do Loop instead of `invi = invi + 1` just do `ws.Visible = True`

Comment: ^^^^^ ... and then maybe an `Exit For`, if you want to unhide only the first hidden sheet.

Comment: thanks @BigBen for your helping, I am trying to put exit for instead of next but it's return an error

Comment: not instead of `Next` it would be a second line inside the `If` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Unhide the first hidden each time it is run:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = False Then
        ws.Visible = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```